# Collision between moving ball & line

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

OK so I have this algorithm that SHOULD detect collision between a ball and a line that the user draws on the screen of the iPad. The code is pretty simple:

```
for (int i = 1; i < currentPlatform; i++) {
        float x1 = xStart[i] -xBall;
        float y1 = yStart[i] - yBall;
        float x2 = xEnd[i] - xBall;
        float y2 = yEnd[i] - yBall;

        float dx = x2 - x1;
        float dy = y2 - y1;
        float dr = sqrtf(powf(dx, 2) + powf(dy, 2));
        float D = x1*y2 - x2*y1;

        float delta = powf((ball.frame.size.height/2), 2)*powf(dr, 2) - powf(D, 2);

        NSLog(@"%f", delta);

        if (delta >= 0) {
            iDir = (((ballVelocity*(sin(angle[i])))*-1)*kRestitution);//*sin(angle[i]));
            jDir = (((ballVelocity*(cos(angle[i]))))*kRestitution*cos(angle[i]));
        }
    }
```

Only problem is, the ball passes through the line undetected! And in the console where delta is printed, it gives crazy answers like -4trillion! Does anyone see something that I am doing wrong with this collision detection?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have the time to try the code now but would it be possible to add a location mark every (lets say) 0.05 seconds when the user is drawing, adding it to an array and then every time the ball moves check to see if it is on a marker.

Alternatively, you could make a bezier curve or some other curve that can be mathematically stored and then check if the position of the ball satisfies the equation of the line.

Comment: This may not be the best approach but if nothing else is working then why not try it.